# Debugging Sitecore Connector for Content Hub

Tags: content-hub

We have a Content Hub instance syncing its content to XP via SSCH (Sitecore Connector for Content Hub).

We are looking for options to troubleshoot some reported issues on the sync process.

With having the following of Content Hub instance can only sync to one environment;
What are different approaches for debugging the connector? Any previous approaches taken would be helpful.